# Objective C NSStream connection always refused

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, tcp, nsstream

I'm trying to setup some NSInput/Output streams in Cocoa and cocoa touch. I'm attempting to create a connection between my Mac and my iPod over Wifi. No matter what, though, I always get **connection refused** errors. I have each devices' address hard coded (since it's just a test). I basically followed Apple's documentation to no avail. I've been stuck with this for days. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Mac side of code.**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    CFReadStreamRef tempRead;
    CFWriteStreamRef tempWrite;

    NSHost *theHost = [NSHost hostWithAddress:@"10.0.1.2"];

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)([theHost address]), 80, &tempRead, &tempWrite);

    myInput = (__bridge NSInputStream *)(tempRead);
    myOutput = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)(tempWrite);

    [myOutput setDelegate:(id<NSStreamDelegate>) self];
    [myInput setDelegate:(id<NSStreamDelegate>) self];

    [myOutput setProperty: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
    [myInput setProperty: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

    [myOutput scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [myInput scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [myOutput open];
    [myInput open];
}
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    NSLog(@"StreamEvent: %lu", streamEvent);
    if(theStream == myOutput)
    {
        if(streamEvent == NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable)
        {
            NSString *myString = @"Hello";

            uint8_t *string1 = (unsigned char *) [myString UTF8String];

            NSInteger written;

            written = [myOutput write: (const uint8_t *) string1 maxLength: strlen((const char *)string1)];
            return;
            }
        }

        if(theStream == myInput)
        {
            NSLog(@"Reading event: %li", streamEvent);
            return;
        }


        NSError *theError = [myOutput streamError];

    NSLog(@"BasicError: %@", [theError localizedDescription]);
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    [myOutput close];
}
```

**iPhone**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CFReadStreamRef tempRead;
    CFWriteStreamRef tempWrite;

    NSHost *theHost = [NSHost hostWithAddress:@"10.0.1.2"];


    [NSStream getStreamsToHost: theHost port:80 inputStream:&inpStream outputStream:&outpStream];


    NSLog(@"Input and output: %@, %@", tempRead, tempWrite);

    myInput = (__bridge NSInputStream *)(tempRead);
    myOutput = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)(tempWrite);

    [myOutput setDelegate:(id<NSStreamDelegate>) self];
    [myInput setDelegate:(id<NSStreamDelegate>) self];

    //If they intercept my voice, woop dee doo, nobody cares!
    [myInput setProperty: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

    [myInput scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [myInput open];

    NSLog(@"DidFinnishLaunchingStatus: %u", [myInput streamStatus]);

    return YES;
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
{
    NSLog(@"TheEvent: %u", streamEvent);

    if(streamEvent == NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable)
    {
        NSLog(@"Reading");

        uint8_t * read1 = NULL;

        unsigned int outputBytes = 0;

        outputBytes = [myInput read: read1 maxLength:1024];

        NSLog(@"outputBytes: %i", outputBytes);
        if(outputBytes)
        {
            NSLog(@"read1: %s", read1);
        }
        return;
    }
}
-(void)dealloc
{
    //Cleanup is tidyness.
    [myInput close];
}
```

Comment: i used the code at that link https://gist.github.com/thefifthcircuit/446256. i can advice you to have a look at this

Comment: That code works for you I assume? I've seen that page before, but it looked so identical to mine that I didn't think much of it. I'll look more carefully over it. By the way, what do you use for your addresses? I use stuff like 10.0.1.5 (for local connections) Is this right?

Comment: hmmm i do not have so much info about the addresses but as i know some addresses can not be used by the user. they belong to system. i used my ip address as a host.

Comment: Have you tried a port that is greater than 1024? Or are you listening port 80 with or without `sudo`? You cannot bind without root privilege on Mac or iOS to a port less than 1024.

Comment: I just realized last night the reason that it wasn't working was because I was trying to make both of them clients. Apparently one of them needs to have an initial listening socket. (I believe at least. I tried a 3rd party library that has a socketServer class and it worked pretty well.) Thanks a lot for the info about the ports by the way.

Comment: @Sequence Can you share the library link you used?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, apparently I don't think that you can connect two devices this way. One of them has to be a server. Currently I'm using SocketKit

https://github.com/unixpickle/SocketKit

But I believe the better solution would be Cocoa ASyncSocket. (Which is what I'm going to try next)